# Split string using reges

Tags: java

I have following string

```
String str = "url:http://www.google.com"
```

Now I want to split the above string using `:`.

If I split above string using `:` then above string split into 3 segments.

But I want whole URL in one segment. How can I get the whole URL?

Three is an one way that I found using substring

```
String webURL = str.substring(4, str.length());
```

Is there any other best way to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [`String.split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) where the second argument is a `limit` (or count). Something like,

```
String str = "url:http://www.google.com";
String[] arr = str.split(":", 2);
System.out.println(arr[1]);
```

Output is (as requested)

```
http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str= "url:http://www.google.com";
// find the first : and take string beyond that     
str = str.substring(str.indexOf(':')+1);
System.out.println(str);
```